# Mongo Db Text Index "term list is too big, max is 4mb"

Tags: mongodb, text, indexing

We use MongoDB on our company for keeping web page texts came from webpage crawler.

When we try to define text index on webPageText column, an error message occurs and failed indexing.
How i can fix this problem. I couldn't find anything on the internet and documentation of MongoDB

The error message like below.

> "errmsg":"tying to index text where term list is too big, max is 4mb"
>
> "code":"16733"

Answer (score -1):

It means the term list is too big for your document, bigger than the maximum of 4mb - your document has too many terms. Index smaller blocks of text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'am collecting every single page text without html tags from 300K web site. I'm holding this texts as a string field in a collection. Did you mean i must dvide different fields these web site texts. How can i do this process over 15 million document? I must text search in this collection. Is there another way you could suggest?

Comment: hi, can you please tell me how do you resolve it, I am having same issue

Comment: @Onurcan yeh, don't use mongo.